# Handle large number of concurrent TCP(even SSL) clients

Tags: c, multithreading, ssl, tcp, concurrency

What is the best approach to handle large number of concurrent TCP clients? (Say 10k)

My server needs to handle concurrent SSL clients (SSL on top of TCP)

After going through a few online articles, I came up with the following design:

- My main thread waits for new connections on epoll
- A new detached thread is spawned for each new accepted client connection, so that `thread_join` need not be explicitly done from the main thread.
- Thread-stack-size is limited to the order of 64k to allow many client connections.

Is this a correct approach? Or are there better approaches?
I am new to this. Any guidance is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

PS: My Server is in C, runs on ubuntu

Comment: The answer to this is OS dependent, eg. on Windows you should use an IO Completion port and a thread pool (thread creation is too expensive), but other OSs differ.

Comment: Thanks. My server runs on Linux. (Ubuntu)

Comment: While quite old http://www.kegel.com/c10k.html shows you some important aspects. And if you have a look at high-performance servers like nginx which handle lots of connections at the same time: they don't use threads but work event-driven.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. I am curious how nginx does that in a single-threaded model. Need to dig into nginx architecture to see how they handle large connections with such efficiency.

Comment: You might examine the source of Apache's HTTP server, and see how the world's most popular HTTP server handle the problem.  Look at their MPM modules, specifically "worker", "event", and "prefork".  Apache's MPM documentation is located at http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mpm.html